# Spring Boot - How to set the default schema for PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

What I am currently doing in my `application.properties` file is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB?currentSchema=mySchema
```

Isn't there another property for this? Since it looks hacky and according to a post (still finding the link sorry, will update later), it is only applicable to PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this is quite old and has no proper answer yet, the right property to set is the following:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=yourschema
```

Comment: And what about JDBC configuration, not JPA?

Comment: Setting currentSchema=mySchema for JDBCTemplate is not working. I'm using postgres 12.

Answer (score 6):

With SpringBoot 2.5.5 the only thing that work for me:

aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=my_schema
```

aplication.yml version:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: my_schema
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try setting the default schema for the jdbc user.

1. ALTER USER user_name SET search_path to 'schema'
2. Did you try this property?

```
spring.datasource.schema
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried this and this works but as much as I possible, I want to set it somewhere in my application (I also don't want to execute sql files for this somewhere).